# how to build real-time google map on Laravel 4

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-4

I'm new to google maps api and I have no idea how to do a real time maps...
for example when there is inserted to a certain lat,lon on database... the map will show that and not doing a refresh(f5) on page... how to do that on Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you insert to db, just re-initialize the map and plot the marker.